What does an array of a struct look like inside a function signature?
Let's say I have a struct like this:
  struct MyType {
    address token;
    uint256 amount;
  }

  function hello(MyType[]) external {
...

What would my function signature (and, therefore, function selector) look like?
"hello(??)"


You'd wrap the primative types in parenthesis and put brackets after them.
For example:
cast sig "hello((address,uint256)[])"

